# Why doesn't Ipython run on Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

Ipython starts only with the administrator account on Windows.

I followed this link but I couldn't solve the problem:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/multi-user/

I need Ipython and others softwares installed with Anaconda to run on domain computers.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda usually doesn't add paths by itself. It says a warning that it can create errors later. Though I installed long before, I might not be correct. You can always access Anaconda directly from the installation directory if you can access those. Or add the paths manually. If still it does't help, please clarify the problem a bit more.

Comment: In the link mentioned above, it is said that a group must be created to add users who must use Anaconda.

But since computers are in the domain and there are many users, adding them is a difficult task.

Would this allow Ipython to run on users without administrator powers?

Comment: The groups are for Linux. In windows you just have to install Anaconda in a directory accessible to all users. Like they mentioned C:/Anaconda or say you install in D:/ drive instead. Any user that can access the executable will be able to run. What directory is your current installation in?

Comment: My installation is in the default directory: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3